# How to calculate torsion angles (phi and psi) from ResidueCoordinates of protein?

Tags: chemistry, bioinformatics

I am trying to compute the torsion angles (phi, psi) from coordinates of protein (using pdb file in Mathematica). I am following the approach explained [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/47084).
The output values are in the range of -180 to +180 But the values that I am getting from my program are not matching with output from [**This Online Tool**](https://swift.cmbi.umcn.nl/servers/html/calc.html).

Also, I don't know Which torsion angle (phi or psi) we are calculating using this method.

**How do we differentiate between different torsion angles?**
**How can we validate our result?**

I WOULD APPRECIATE ANY SUGGESTION

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Import the coordinates from pdb files with Import function. Then follow the steps from this link. https://www.math.fsu.edu/~quine/MB_10/6_torsion.pdf